# Google maps Activity not working after update sdk

Tags: android, google-maps

After update to android studio 1.3.2 and the latest version of sdk , i have this error on my Apps please any one have any idea to resolve this problem.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7895000 but found 7571000.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzad(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzy.zzaG(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzy.zzaF(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzwP(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreate(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1939)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:978)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1277)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2232)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:278)
            at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:78)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:329)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944)
            at com.mac125.muslimtools_tunisie.activities.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you/Android Studio did not update the Google Play Services Version correctly.

From the error message, you can see Android Studio is complaining about the outdated version 7571000 (which is 7.5), and the current version should be 7895000 (7.8)

[image]

Changing this number should fix the problem.

I am guessing that you are following some kind of tutorial and you copied their manifest, for usually people put `@integer/google_play_services_version` and reference to the integer/google_play_services_version for the newest version (even Android Studio display it as a number)

Comment: yes this is it (y) , i'm do invalidate for Android studio and restarted it then the version code of gms.version fixes to 7895000, :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

in your xml

Comment: well, can you attach your xml file? are you sure the <meta-data> is inside of <application> and out side of <activity>?